# How to choose contour for computing this particular real integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve a exercise from my Complex Analysis book. The exercise says:

> Show that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac {\cos(x)}{x^a} \, dx=\Gamma(1-a) \sin \left(\frac{\pi a} 2 \right)$ where $0<a<1.$

I am having trouble in choosing proper contour for this integral. Could someone please explain me how should i choose contour for computing the same integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(z) = e^{-z} z^{s-1}$ is holomorphic on $Re(z) > 0$ with exponential decay as $Re(z) \to +\infty$, with the Cauchy integral theorem you get that for every $Re(b) > 0$ : 
$$Re(s) > 0, \qquad\qquad\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-z}z^{s-1}dz=\int_0^{b \infty} e^{-z}z^{s-1}dz $$
$$ = \int_0^\infty e^{-bx}(bx)^{s-1}d(bx) = b^{s} \int_0^\infty e^{-bx}x^{s-1}dx$$

Now for $Re(s) \in (0,1)$, you can extend it by continuity to $b = \pm i$ and get
$$\Gamma(s) =e^{i \pi s/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-ix}x^{s-1}dx=e^{-i \pi s/2} \int_0^\infty e^{ix}x^{s-1}dx$$
i.e. for $Re(a) \in (-1,0)$ : 
$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty \cos(x) x^{-a}dx = \frac{e^{ i\pi (1- a)/ 2}+e^{- i \pi(1-a) / 2}}{2}\Gamma(1-a) = \sin( \pi a/ 2)\Gamma(1-a)}$$

Comment: Thank you..but mainly i am interested in solving the question by contour integration

Comment: @VictorBarg there is no other way, and the 1st step is a contour integral

Comment: I think there is a way by choosing the contour to be the quarter circle in first quadrant minus a small quarter circle around origin(to avoid origin) Thanks

Comment: @VictorBarg it is what I did ..

Comment: Then i think i don't follow your answer properly..i would be happy if you would add some more details in step 1 thank you.

Comment: Since $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $Re(z) > 0$ and everything converges : $\int_0^\infty+\int_\infty^{b \infty}+\int_{b \infty}^0 f(z)dz = 0$. Now $\int_\infty^{b \infty} f(z)dz=0$ so it leaves us with the 1st equality

Comment: And if you are affraid of what happens at $z=0$, use as you said a small piece of circle for avoiding it, and let it $\to 0$, and do the same at $z= \infty$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48813/discussion-between-victor-barg-and-user1952009).

Comment: @VictorBarg is it clear now ? And for extending it to $Re(b) = 0$, you need to prove that for $Re(s) \in (0,1)$ : $\int_1^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-ix}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_1^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-(i+\epsilon)x}dx$, for example by integrating by parts (making it absolutely convergent)

Comment: Sorry its not..i am bit confused about the contour you're taking in step $1$,could you please clarify?Sorry for troubling you

Comment: @VictorBarg come on... If $f(z)$ is holomorphic then $\int_A^B+\int_B^C+\int_C^Af(z)dz = 0$. Here $A = 0,B = +\infty,C= b \infty$ with $Re(b) > 0$ and $f(z) = z^{s-1}e^{-z}$

Comment: Sorry.Its clear now,i was very silly. Thanks a lot.